# Email validation passes without domain extension

Tags: aurelia

I am using `Aurelia-Validation` in my project and trying to validate email address. When I add an email `example@g`, it passes the validation. Shouldn't email validation have `.com`, `.net`, etc extension at the end to pass the validation? See the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8BO8AQ) link as an example.

Here is the screenshot to show what I mean:

[image: 2018-04-25 10_09_35-plunker]

Comment: This is a valid e-mail actually, so to speak. Someone can always add "real" e-mail like `nice.girl@gmajl.com`, but that doesn't mean it's a valid e-mail either (valid account in the domain's MX). So you have to clarify what kind of validation you really want. `g` may not be routable in the Internet, but can be in the Intranet.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I added the matches pattern and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit nit-picky, but like emix already pointed out in comments, the validation regex used by `aurelia-validation` is currently the widely accepted standard as specified by [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address). This is the same regex as documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Basic_validation) and [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#ref-for-willful-violation%E2%91%A3).

[Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e54b14cf9aa636c08eb61a3d8087226da88d27d4/dom/html/input/SingleLineTextInputTypes.h#L123) seems to follow this specification for validating `input type="email"` at least. I couldn't find any official sources on chrome or edge though.

The JavaScript version of that regex is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

In simple terms this translates to:

1. (required) before the `@` symbol, any number of alphanumeric characters and (certain) symbols
2. (required) after the `@` symbol, between 1 and 63 alphanumeric characters or hyphens (and cannot start or end with a hyphen)
3. (optional) same as 2 (but starting with a period), repeated for any number of times

If you want to restrict this validation to emails which are routable in the internet, simply change the asterisk `*` at the end of the regex to a plus `+`. That keeps the regex identical except there must now be *at least one* segment starting with a period.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Made change to my validation rule with below code:

Original code:

```
ValidationRules.ensure('setEmail')
    .displayName('Email')
    .required()
    .email()
    .on(this);
```

Modified code with matches pattern:

```
ValidationRules.ensure('setEmail')
    .displayName('Email')
    .required()
    .email()
    .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)
    .on(this);
```

See the screenshot:

**Invalid:**

[image]

**Valid:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions I think we can use `Validators.pattern(REGEX_VALID_EMAIL)` instead of `Validators.email` in the `formControl` validator.

and `REGEX_VALID_EMAIL` can be the following.

```
const REGEX_VALID_EMAIL = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$/
;
```